# Best Webhosting for ASP.NET MVC1 or MVC2 and SQL Server 2008 with FILESTREAM support

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream, web-hosting

I am looking for a best web host to host my application developed with the following technologies.

1. ASP.NET MVC1
2. SQL Server 2008 with FILESTREAM
   support

I first tried to host on DiscountASP.net. After creating account, I realized that they do not support `FILESTREAM` in `SQL Server 2008`. I checked with `Godaddy` as well. They do not seem to support `SQL Server 2008`.

I appreciate if you can point me to some good web hosts for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I had the same question so here is an answer.

GoDaddy Pro can support FILESTREAM via a virtual dedicated server.  They run a VM running Windows Server 2008.  Then you install a SQL Server that supports FILESTREAM (2008R2, 2012, 2014).

So, I would further guess that any service that can provide you with a dedicated virtual machine can ultimately give you the FILESTREAM service that you need.

I have verified that the following hosted services do not support FILESTREAM:

- Amazon AWS doesn't support FILESTREAM
- Winhost doesn't support FILESTREAM

http://www.webhostingbus.com/enabling-filestream-option-on-the-sql-server-database/